# Best practice to have c# winform gui update continuously via Redis versus polling database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, redis

I am developing a c# winform gui that revolves around a few datagridviews that need to be updated at some manageable interval depending on # of updates, somewhere around the 1 - 3 second mark.

Currently, upon startup, it retrieves the current batch of data for the grids from a mysql database, then listens to various redis channels for updates/adds/deletes to those grids.  These updates are handled by the redis multiplexer and heavy calculations are offloaded to worker threads, then the gui is updated.  So essentially it is one to one, meaning one update/add/delete is processed and the gui is then updated.  This works well enough so far however during a crunch of data i'm beginning to notice slowness, it should not happen since i'm expecting much heavier loads in the future.

As the system throughput grows, where it is currently at most around 100 redis messages every couple of seconds, this should be designed to handle thousands.

**Conceptually, when it comes to general gui design in this fashion, would it be better to do one of the following:**

1. **Decouple** from the current 1 to 1 update scenario described above, redis msg -> process -> update gui, and have all redis messages queue in a list or datatable, then on a timer poll this awaiting update queue by the gui and update.  This way the gui is not flooded, it updates on its own schedule.
2. Since these updates coming from redis are also persisted in the mysql database, just **ignore redis completely**, and at some timed interval query the database, however this would probably result in an entire requeue since it will be tough to know what has changed since the last pull.
3. Do away with attempting to update the gui in semi-realtime fashion, and **only provide a summary** view then if user digs in, retrieve data accordingly, but this still runs in to the same problem as the data that is then being viewed should be updated, albeit a smaller subset.  However, there exist tons of sophisticated c# enterprise level applications that represent large amounts of data updating especially in the finance industry and seem to work just fine.

What is best practice here?  I prefer options 1 or 2 because in theory it should be able to work.

thank you in advance

Comment: If you have performance problems, Start by *measuring*. Otherwise you risk improving the wrong part. Some profiling data should help you make an informed decision about the best approach for your particular case.

Comment: @JonasH yes agreed, i have done this to some extent, however currently given the 1 to 1 update scenario as described, i can only measure each update time which seem fine, it's when scaling up is the problem but still there is no 'batch' update to measure, just individual.   Thoughts on overall concept best practice?

Comment: Any of the approaches *might* be viable. But it really depends on times for 1. Extracting data from DB, 2. Applying deltas to your data model, 3. Redrawing/updating the UI. It is also possible that performance in each of these areas could be improved. So it is really difficult to provide any concrete recommendations.